# Putting records in new table that don't have 6 or more different addresses for same name

Tags: ms-access, unique

If the names repeated is more than 6 and there are six different addresses for that same name, then I don't want to output them to the KeepThese table:

```
harry baker 1 street
harry baker 2 street
harry baker 3 street
harry baker 4 street
harry baker 5 street
harry baker 6 street
donald ross 11th street
```

So harry baker should be excluded from new table. donald ross should be included in new table.

This is existing query that I have:

```
SELECT F.* INTO KeepThese
FROM final_output AS F 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT F.fullName FROM final_output 
AS F LEFT JOIN (SELECT fullName FROM final_output 
AS F GROUP BY fullName HAVING COUNT(*) >=6)  
AS NamesToReject ON NamesToReject.fullName = F.fullName WHERE NamesToReject.ID IS NULL)  
AS NamesToKeep ON NamesToKeep.fullName  = F.fullName;
```

This returns "Enter Parameter Value NamesToReject.ID" 
But this is best I could come up with.

Comment: Your existing query doesn't work because in the subselect you've aliased as `NamesToReject` does not include the ID field in it's SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about :

```
SELECT *
FROM final_output AS f 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT t.fullname 
     FROM final_output AS t 
     GROUP BY t.fullname 
     HAVING Count(t.fullname)>=6)  AS Ex 
ON f.fullname=Ex.fullname
WHERE Ex.fullname Is Null
```

Up to this point, any name and address combination with less than six of the same name will be shown.

If this next statement is added, only one of each name will be shown with one address for that name, chosen at random.

```
AND Nz([address],"None") In (
     SELECT TOP 1 Nz(address,"None") 
     FROM  final_output t 
     WHERE t.fullname = f.fullname 
     ORDER BY fullname, Nz(address,"None") )
```

Comment: Oops, short one bracket. try it now.

Comment: Thanks for response. It says "data type mismatch in criteria expression".

Comment: Okay, I have tested with the latest version.

Comment: Thanks it works but the only issue is if there are less than 6 different addresses, they are kept: harry baker 1 street
harry baker 2 street. Only when there are 6 or more different addresses are they removed. Your query removes any duplicate name. So there may be duplicate names, if they have less than 6 different addresses.

Comment: It was not clear that you wanted to show up to all five name and address combinations, if they were available.